# Arranging $6$ orange marbles and $6$ red marbles in a circle.

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to count the number of ways to arrange $6$ orange marbles and $6$ red marbles in a circle, if rotations of a given arrangement are considered the same (and marbles of the same color are identical).

I realize this can be done by considering the $12$ rotations of the circle and trying to count the number of arrangements each rotation leaves fixed, or by breaking this up into cases according to how the orange marbles are spaced, but is there a more elementary way to work this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\frac{12!}{6!6!}$ arrangements if we do *not* identify per rotation.
For all divisors $d$ of $6$, you need to count how many arrangements are invariant under rotating by $2d$ steps (the number is $n_d=\frac{(2d)!}{d!d!}$) and employ the inclusion-exclusion principle.

From this we get that the count of arrangements having *no* rotational symmetry is
$$ n_{6}-2n_3-n_2+n_1$$
the count of those having a threefold but not sixfold symmetry is 
$$ n_{3}-n_1$$
the count of those having a twofold but not sixfold symmetry is 
$$ n_{2}-n_1.$$
Thus after identification modulo rotation, we obtain
$$ \frac{n_{6}-2n_3-n_2+n_1}{12}+\frac{n_2-n_1}{6}+\frac{n_3-n_1}{4}+\frac{n_1}2$$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen- the question says "rotations of a given arrangement are considered the same".

Comment: Thanks -- I hadn't seen this method of solution before.